# Resize unity webgl canvas non-responsive

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I am trying to resize the Unity's WebGL canvas to fit to the aspect ratio of browser window. I do not want it to be responsive, just resize to fit in the window.

How do I achieve this in css/html?

I tried setting the window to 100% for both width and height, but it still does not scale. What am  I doing wrong?

```js
var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/WebGL_ResponsiveBuild.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/WebGL_ResponsiveBuild.data",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/WebGL_ResponsiveBuild.framework.js",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/WebGL_ResponsiveBuild.wasm",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "DefaultCompany",
        productName: "WebGL",
        productVersion: "0.1",
      };

      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var mobileWarning = document.querySelector("#unity-mobile-warning");

      // By default Unity keeps WebGL canvas render target size matched with
      // the DOM size of the canvas element (scaled by window.devicePixelRatio)
      // Set this to false if you want to decouple this synchronization from
      // happening inside the engine, and you would instead like to size up
      // the canvas DOM size and WebGL render target sizes yourself.
      // config.matchWebGLToCanvasSize = false;

      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        container.className = "unity-mobile";
        // Avoid draining fillrate performance on mobile devices,
        // and default/override low DPI mode on mobile browsers.
        config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
        mobileWarning.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(() => {
          mobileWarning.style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        canvas.style.width = "1920px";
        canvas.style.height = "1080px";
      }
      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";
          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
```

```css
body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
#unity-container { position: absolute }
#unity-container.unity-desktop { left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
#unity-container.unity-mobile { width: 100%; height: 100% }
#unity-canvas { background: #F3F3F0 }
.unity-mobile #unity-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
#unity-loading-bar { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); display: none }
#unity-logo { width: 154px; height: 130px; background: url('') no-repeat center }
#unity-progress-bar-empty { width: 141px; height: 18px; margin-top: 10px; background: url('progress-bar-empty-light.png') no-repeat center }
#unity-progress-bar-full { width: 0%; height: 18px; margin-top: 10px; background: url('progress-bar-full-light.png') no-repeat center }
#unity-footer { position: relative }
.unity-mobile #unity-footer { display: none }
#unity-webgl-logo { float:left; width: 204px; height: 38px; background: url('') no-repeat center }
#unity-build-title { float: right; margin-right: 10px; line-height: 38px; font-family: arial; font-size: 18px }
#unity-fullscreen-button { float: right; width: 38px; height: 38px; background: url('fullscreen-button.png') no-repeat center }
#unity-mobile-warning { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 5%; transform: translate(-50%); background: white; padding: 10px; display: none }
```

```html
    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas" width=1920 height=1080></canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-mobile-warning">
        WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.
      </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">WebGL</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

var w = window.innerWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight;

Get the window size with vanilla js and add them here:

```
    canvas.style.width = "1920px";  <-- w
    canvas.style.height = "1080px"; <-- h
```